# Harmonic oscillator with potential multiplied by a constant

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I know the solution for the classic problem; a particle in an harmonic oscillator with the given potential;

$ V = m\omega^2x^2/2$.

Let's denote the eigenfunctions by $ \phi_n $ and the eigenvalues by $ E_n $

Assume now that the particle is in potential of:

$ V=2m\omega^2x^2 $

How can I  express the eigenfunctions and energies of this state using what I know about the classic problem ( $\phi_n $ and $E_n$)

I tried to write Shcrodinger equation with this new potential and tried to bring it to the regular form with the change of the wave function and the energy multiplied by a constant factor, but I cant see how to do it actually.

Any ideas?

Comment: How would you derive the eigenfunctions and energies for the original potential? It's the same process with the new potential.

Comment: Im pretty sure there's a shorter way than solve it all over again.

Comment: I'm assuming by classical you mean "standard" rather than "non-quantum"? Also isn't this just a rescaling of the frequency? E.g. define $\tilde{\omega}=2ω,$ then $V=m^2\tilde{\omega}^2/2$ and you are back to the original potential in terms of $\tilde{\omega}$? Non quantum-mechnically, this just corresponds to increasing the oscillator strength $k$ by a factor 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve it for:

$$ V = \frac 1 2 m\omega'^2x^2$$

with

$\omega' = \frac 1 2 \omega$

which constitutes adding a prime to all the $\omega$'s in your current solution.